# why i get this " -bash: ROUGE-1.5.5.pl: command not found error " error?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to evaluate the system generated summaries using ROUGE. I have used the command line bellow but i get this`-bash: ROUGE-1.5.5.pl: command not found`error. what is the problem?

`ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -n 4 -w 1.2 -m  -2 4 -u -c 95 -r 1000 -f A -p 0.5 -t 0 -a -d rougejk.in`

Comment: How is this related to Perl? What is ROUGE?

Comment: Try `./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -n 4 -w 1.2 -m  -2 4 -u -c 95 -r 1000 -f A -p 0.5 -t 0 -a -d rougejk.in`

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for debugging cmd-line invocations, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: The perl script is not in a directory which is in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your file "ROUGE-1.5.5.pl" isn't defined in your PATH variable, or your file isn't in a folder defined in PATH :

```
$> echo $PATH
```

If you want to add the path to the folder containing "ROUGE-1.5.5.pl" :

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/folder"
```

Then you will be able to run your command as described.
You can add this line to your .bashrc, if you want this to be permanent.

Else you have to run the command like this (from your script location) :

```
./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -n 4 -w 1.2 -m -2 4 -u -c 95 -r 1000 -f A -p 0.5 -t 0 -a -d rougejk.in
```